# How did they make such layout - which elements they used?

Tags: android, android-layout

At the moment, I am using [Euro 2012 app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.imano.euro2012.row) and it has some interesting layout parts. If you go to matches->knockout screen, you'll see 3 screens like this.

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you slide left or right, you move between them not like between one activity to another, but just like all these elements are laid on one big canvas and you slide each screen into focus. Even thou, if you slide left/right, the screen cannot be stopped in the way that half of each image is visible, so I guess it's not a big canvas. Somehow you can slide screen like one big image, and yet it always lock perfectly as if they used 3 activities for this.

How did the do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html), available in Android support package and described in their [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).

Comment: but in view pager if you stop between two pages it shows both pages as he mention in question it's not stopping in between swapping of pages..

Comment: @Jay Which element did you use exactly?

Comment: the complete discussion is moving around view pager that's not major thing, i thought actually you asked how they can make such layouts not how slide between ... so, i provided explanation, and about view pager it's up to you to customize it in my case if you as you said if moving between pages it's not stop between pages but if you forcefully drag slowly it shows you both pages, but when you leave it automatically fits to screen.

Answer (score 0):

The designing is not so much difficult, As i think to draw that boxes showing quarterfinals, semifinals.

They having layout( we can do by placing image in background also).
The major role played by FrameLayout which shows you that effect(emphasis), the flages are fetch from url as matches are decided(not essentially images only names are sufficient as flags came inside app and gets applied as updated).

After your click i think the start image gets change it's just replacing that image with new one.

As you said they are not on single canvas (but if they did customization of heir Viewpager that it's not stopping in between activities), but i think it's on single canvas.

If your taking about quickness of loading and all it's up to you as much code and processing you optimized it gives you smooth feel and fast processing.

We can appreciate the work but we can not say it's too much difficult as i think it's quit easy...

Hope this explanation helps you to understand ....